# Can't cd to directory of programs like apache or tomcat on ec2: permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-http-server, amazon-ec2

hi I have setup tomcat 7 through yum on an ec2 instance.  I have access to the user ec2-user by default through aws from launching the ec2 instance.

I am trying to simply look at my tomcat logs with the command:

```
 cd: /usr/share/tomcat7/logs/
```

I get the error: Permission denied

ls -al shows the permissions on the tomcat7 folder as:
     drwxrwxr-x   3 root tomcat tomcat7

the same for logs shows:
     lrwxrwxrwx  1 root tomcat logs

I have read that the ec2-user has root permissions.

I attempt to sudo with the cd command but I get the error: sudo: cd: command not found

How can I get into this directory to see my logs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried switching to the root account using `sudo su`?

Answer (score 2):

`cd` isn't a program, so you can't `sudo` it. Do `sudo -s` and then `cd` into the directory.